# Image won't upload when implemented, but when I try the image PHP script alone it uploads fine

Tags: php, image, upload

I have an image upload script, originally I kept it in a file called "upload.php" which JUST contained the PHP upload script and a simple file browser and submit button. This works fine, the image uploads without any problems and goes into the "images/uploads" directory.

However, when I try and implement this into another page it all goes belly-up and won't upload. I've tried various different things but I'm starting to reach the extent of my PHP knowledge so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's the code for the index.php page (the page where I'm trying to implement the image script):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    if(session_is_registered("username")) {

    include("includes/config.php");
    mysql_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die("Could not connect to database" . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database);

    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE items SET name='" . $_POST['name'] . "', price='" . $_POST['price'] . "', description='" . $_POST['description'] . "', hidden='" . $_POST['hidden'] . "' WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'] . "'") or die("Could not update" . mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM items WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: index.php?p=edit&c=" . $c);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (name, price, description, category, hidden) VALUES('" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['price'] . "', '" . $_POST['description'] . "', '" . $_POST['category'] . "', '" . $_POST['hidden'] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
    }

    //define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
    define ("MAX_SIZE","100");

    //This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file is an image by checking the extension.
    function getExtension($str) {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
    }

    //This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error found) and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures. If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
    $errors=0;
    //checks if the form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not upload the file, otherwize we will do more tests
    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
    //print error message
    echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
    //get the size of the image in bytes
    //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }

    //we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
    $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
    //the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
    $newname="../images/uploads/".$image_name;
    //we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
    $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
    if (!$copied)
    {
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }}}}

    //If no errors registred, print the success message
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$errors)
    {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title>Silverdale Buxton Ltd | Admin CP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/admin.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formalize.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/elements/sd-logo.jpg" alt="Silverdale Buxton Ltd" border="0" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="title">Admin CP</li>
                <li><a href="../">View website</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php?do=logout">Log-out <pre><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></pre>?</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"><a href="index.php?p=add">Add New Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?p=edit">View/Edit Items</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <?php if(!isset($p)) { // DEFAULT PAGE VIEWED AT INDEX.PHP ?>
            <h1>Welcome to the Admin Control Panel</h1>
            <p>This control panel enables you to manage (add/modify/delete) items for sale from the Silverdale database.</p>
            <p>It's simple enough to use; just click one of the buttons in the top right of the page.</p>
            <p>If you have any problems please contact me on <span>01782 269494</span> (ask for Chrish) or e-mail me at <span><a href="mailto:chrish@albionmedia.biz">chrish [at] albionmedia [dot] biz</a></span>.</p>

            <?php } else if($p == "add") { // ADD NEW ITEMS PAGE ?>
            <h1>Add New Item</h1>
            <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
            ?>
            <form method="post" name="editor" action="">
                <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" />

                <label for="price">Price &pound;GBP</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" maxlength="9" />

                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select name="category">
                    <?php
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value=\"" . $row['catname'] . "\">" . $row['catname'] . "</option>\n                  ";
                        }
                        echo "\n";
                    ?>
                </select>

                <label for="description">Product Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" cols="70" rows="20" maxlength="2000"></textarea>

                <label for="image">Image Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" />

                <label for="hidden">Hide this item from market page?</label>
                <div class="visibility">
                    <span class="show">
                        Show
                        <input type="radio" name="hidden" value="0" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="hide">
                        Hide
                        <input type="radio" name="hidden" value="1" />
                    </span>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Product" />
            </form>
            <p><a href="index.php?p=edit&c=<?php echo $row['category']; ?>">&larr; Go Back</a></p>

            <?php } else if($p == "edit") { // VIEW/EDIT ITEMS PAGE ?>
            <h1>View/Edit Items</h1>
            <?php if(!isset($c)) { ?>
            <p>Please select a category.</p>
            <ul>
            <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?p=edit&c=" . $row['catname'] . "\">" . $row['catname'] . "</a></li>\n";
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } else if(isset($c) && !isset($id)) { ?>
            <p>Items in category: <strong><?php echo $c; ?></strong></p>
            <ul>
            <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category='" . $c . "'");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?p=edit&c=" . $row['category'] . "&id=" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</a></li>\n";
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="index.php?p=edit">&larr; Go Back</a></p>
            <?php
            } else if(isset($id)) {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category='" . $c . "' AND id='" . $id . "'");
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                if($row['hidden'] == 1) {
                    $vis = "hidden";
                } else {
                    $vis = "visible";
                }
            ?>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="editor" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?p=edit&c=" . $row['category'] . "&id=" . $row['id']; ?>">
                <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />

                <label for="price">Price &pound;GBP</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" />

                <label for="description">Product Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" cols="70" rows="20" maxlength="2000"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>

                <label for="hidden">Hide this item from market page? <strong style="<?php if($vis == "hidden") { echo "color: #de4949"; } else { echo "color: #62a443"; } ?>">Item is currently <u><?php echo $vis; ?></u>.</strong></label>
                <div class="visibility">
                    <span class="show">
                        Show
                        <input type="radio" name="hidden" value="0"<?php if($vis == "visible") { echo "checked=\"yes\""; } ?> />
                    </span>
                    <span class="hide">
                        Hide
                        <input type="radio" name="hidden" value="1"<?php if($vis == "hidden") { echo "checked=\"yes\""; } ?> />
                    </span>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Product" />
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Product" class="delete" />
            </form>
            <p><a href="index.php?p=edit&c=<?php echo $row['category']; ?>">&larr; Go Back</a></p>
            <? } ?>

            <?php } else { // IF SOMEONE MESSES WITH ?P= OR SOMETHING ELSE GOES WRONG ?>
            <h1>Error 404:</h1>
            <p>Page URL not recognised. Please <a href="index.php">click here</a>.</p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2010 Albion Media. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.albionmedia.biz/" target="_blank">albionmedia.biz</a></p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.css3finalize-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery.formalize.js"></script>
    <?php if($p == "edit") { ?><script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.delete').click(function() {
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item? This will delete all information and images associated with it and CAN NOT be un-done!")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script><?php } ?>
 </body>
</html>
<?php
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

And this is the upload.php script that works fine:

```
<?php
    //define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
    define ("MAX_SIZE","100");

    //This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file is an image by checking the extension.
    function getExtension($str) {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
    }

    //This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error found) and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures. If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
    $errors=0;
    //checks if the form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not upload the file, otherwize we will do more tests
    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
    //print error message
    echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
    //get the size of the image in bytes
    //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }

    //we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
    $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
    //the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
    $newname="../images/uploads/".$image_name;
    //we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
    $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
    if (!$copied)
    {
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
    }}}}

    //If no errors registred, print the success message
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$errors)
    {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title>Image Upload | Admin CP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 </head>

 <body>
    <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I should probably also note that I don't get any errors on this page, even when I submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your implementation, change your form to:

```
    <form method="post" name="editor" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

                ...
                <label for="image">Image Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" />
```

[from the W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> By specifying the enctype value of
>   "multipart/form-data", each file's
>   contents will be packaged for
>   submission in a separate section of a
>   multipart document.

Comment: That worked, sort of. The file appears to upload, but when I check the directory it's supposed to be uploading to, it's not actually uploaded. This is the path: $newname="../images/uploads/".$image_name;

Comment: I just noticed this error at the top: "Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/testserver/clients/silverdale/admin/index.php on line 40"

Answer (score 0):

Add, enctype="multipart/form-data" 
while submitting your form for image upload